# SUM does not work

Tags: python, numpy, sum

I wrote a  function in PYTHON as followed, but I found that the SUM does not work correctly in it.

```
def func(a,*b):
    c = np.array([1,a,a**2,a**3])
    d = np.array(b)
    return sum(c*d)


a = 10
b = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4]

aa = np.array([1,a,a**2,a**3])
bb = np.array(b)
c = func(a,b)

print sum(aa*bb),c
```

The output of the code is `432.1 [  1.00000000e-01   2.00000000e+00   3.00000000e+01   4.00000000e+02]`.

Does anyone know  what happened to SUM here?

Comment: i'm not entirely sure what output you expect?

Comment: @njzk2 432.1 is preferable for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `func` function signature captures `b` as a list of arguments using `*` as a catch-all marker. This makes `b` a list of lists, with one argument. But to define `bb` you don't do the same; you pass in *just* the list.

Either do:

```
bb = np.array([b])
```

or do:

```
def func(a, b):
    c = np.array([1,a,a**2,a**3])
    d = np.array(b)
    return sum(c*d)
```

or

```
def func(a, *b):
    c = np.array([1,a,a**2,a**3])
    d = np.array(b[0])
    return sum(c*d)
```

to make the two codepaths equivalent.